# Creating DTO to shape data from the back-end JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I would like to create DTO to shape data from a server H2 and merge data from two or three entities on JHipster.

I never used DTO. Do you know where I can find the way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, you can create one manually by defining a simple class with only getters and setters and then you create a Mapper class that will fill the object from the entities. You can see an example in your JHipster project by looking at `UserMapper` class.

Alternatively, JHipster uses MapStruct to generate them when you select DTO option but frankly it's simpler to code it manually.